# Memtest how to i find out which stick is failing

Tags: windows-7, windows

I havent had a lot of problems, but some cpu related error blue screens when ive been pushing the overclock.. Ran prime 95 and the cpu does fine, never crashs. So i ran memtest here are my results, what do?

001a57179c0 tst 5 6743mb 
001a57179c4 tst 6 6743mb

Here is the IMAGE. Imgur.com/14p9rxq

Comment: there is a lack of results...

Comment: Those were the only errors even when it was finished

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find a bad stick of RAM is to test one stick at a time.  Take all your memory out, put one in and test it.  If it passes, take it out and put the next one in.  Naturally, you should test all of them, in case more than one is bad.

Comment: It’s not the easiest way—it’s the _only_ way. Indeed, to rule out defective slots/channels, you’d have to test each module in every slot.